# replace text between curly bracket and remove <> in the string

Tags: sql-server-2005

How can I use replace statement in SQL query to replace/remove all the text inside the curly bracket and the curly bracket itself. I have many similar text like that with curly bracket in my database, can I use regular expression or something similar?

E.g. `@DN = value1!!{value2}<value3>`
---> `VALUE1!!VALUE3`
the number of characters is very dynamic so can't charindex with number's.
From previous discussions i used this

```
STUFF(DN, PATINDEX('%{ }%', DN), LEN(DN), '')
```

which is only giving `NULL` value.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
Declare @DN varchar(100)

Set @DN = 'value1!!{value2}<value3>'

Select Left(@DN, CHARINDEX('{',@DN) -1) + REPLACE(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(@DN, CHARINDEX('}', @DN)+1, (LEN(@DN) - CHARINDEX('}', @DN))), '<',''),'>','')
```

It's messy but will give you.

`value1!!<value3>`

Comment: Hi Barry, it works to get Value1!!<Value2> but can you plz help to get this: Value1!!Value2. This is to remove < and > from the string and only give Value2. the correct one would be: Value1!!Value2. Thanks.

Comment: that worked thanks a lot. when i use this in select statement it works well but when i try to enter the select result into a table  - then i end up getting error: Msg 536, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
Invalid length parameter passed to the SUBSTRING function.
The statement has been terminated. do you why?

Comment: You probably have values in the column that don't conform to the pattern you specified. (values that don't have `{` in them or values that are blank. You would have to edit your question and add in further details of your table and column values.

Comment: Thanks Barry for all your responses. you are right. there are some tables where the data is not accurate which is not big number and i will remove those values from the tables which will solve the purpose.